# Varnish losing and reacquiring log - connection dropped

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I am experiencing intermittent empty replies or connection reset errors from Varnish (6.5) for a specific route. This is the VCL in question (part of a larger set of VCLs but this is what the route is using):

```
vcl 4.1;

import gcis;
import std;

include "/etc/varnish/conf.d/backend_default.vcl";
include "/etc/varnish/conf.d/acl.vcl";


sub vcl_init {
    new idmap = gcis.idmap();
}


sub vcl_recv {
    if (!client.ip ~ internal_acl) {
        return (synth (
                405,
                "Client IP " + client.ip +
                " is not allowed to access this service."));
    }
}


sub vcl_deliver {
    // If the request was for reloading the ACL, reload the list here.
    if (req.url == "/svc/reload_acl") {
        std.log(
            idmap.load(std.getenv("GCISWG_ACL_FILE"))
            + " restricted identifiers reloaded from database."
        );

        ban ("req.url ~ ^/iiif/");
        ban ("req.url == /svc/dump_acl");
    }
}
```

If I send the following request repeatedly:

```
curl -iXPOST varnish/svc/reload_acl
```

Sometimes I get the expected response; other times I get `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` and other times yet `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`.

The varnishlog entries for the empty reply look as the following:

```
varnish_1      | *   << BeReq    >> 9         
varnish_1      | -   Begin          bereq 8 pass
varnish_1      | -   VCL_use        svc
varnish_1      | -   Timestamp      Start: 1623449680.866799 0.000000 0.000000
varnish_1      | -   BereqMethod    POST
varnish_1      | -   BereqURL       /svc/reload_acl
varnish_1      | -   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
varnish_1      | -   BereqHeader    User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
varnish_1      | -   BereqHeader    Accept: */*
varnish_1      | -   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 172.18.0.5
varnish_1      | -   BereqHeader    host: varnish
varnish_1      | -   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 9
varnish_1      | -   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
varnish_1      | -   VCL_return     fetch
varnish_1      | -   BackendOpen    32 default 172.18.0.8 8080 172.18.0.9 34554 reuse
varnish_1      | -   Timestamp      Bereq: 1623449680.866890 0.000091 0.000091
varnish_1      | -   Timestamp      Beresp: 1623449680.878314 0.011515 0.011424
varnish_1      | -   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
varnish_1      | -   BerespStatus   201
varnish_1      | -   BerespReason   CREATED
varnish_1      | -   BerespHeader   Server: nginx/1.18.0
varnish_1      | -   BerespHeader   Date: Fri, 11 Jun 2021 22:14:40 GMT
varnish_1      | -   BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
varnish_1      | -   BerespHeader   Content-Length: 31
varnish_1      | -   BerespHeader   Connection: keep-alive
varnish_1      | -   VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
varnish_1      | -   VCL_return     deliver
varnish_1      | -   Filters        
varnish_1      | -   Storage        malloc Transient
varnish_1      | -   Fetch_Body     3 length stream
varnish_1      | -   BackendClose   32 default recycle
varnish_1      | -   Timestamp      BerespBody: 1623449680.878392 0.011593 0.000078
varnish_1      | -   Length         31
varnish_1      | -   BereqAcct      129 0 129 167 31 198
varnish_1      | -   End            
varnish_1      | 
varnish_1      | *   << Session  >> 7         
varnish_1      | -   Begin          sess 0 HTTP/1
varnish_1      | -   SessOpen       172.18.0.5 57306 nossl 172.18.0.9 80 1623449680.866658 30
varnish_1      | -   Link           req 8 rxreq
varnish_1      | -   VSL            flush
varnish_1      | -   End            synth
varnish_1      | 
varnish_1      | *   << Request  >> 8         
varnish_1      | -   Begin          req 7 rxreq
varnish_1      | -   Timestamp      Start: 1623449680.866744 0.000000 0.000000
varnish_1      | -   Timestamp      Req: 1623449680.866744 0.000000 0.000000
varnish_1      | -   VCL_use        main
varnish_1      | -   ReqStart       172.18.0.5 57306 nossl
varnish_1      | -   ReqMethod      POST
varnish_1      | -   ReqURL         /svc/reload_acl
varnish_1      | -   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
varnish_1      | -   ReqHeader      Host: varnish
varnish_1      | -   ReqHeader      User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
varnish_1      | -   ReqHeader      Accept: */*
varnish_1      | -   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 172.18.0.5
varnish_1      | -   VCL_call       RECV
varnish_1      | -   VCL_use        svc via svc_vcl
varnish_1      | -   VCL_return     vcl
varnish_1      | -   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 172.18.0.5
varnish_1      | -   VCL_call       RECV
varnish_1      | -   VCL_acl        MATCH internal_acl "172.0.0.0/8"
varnish_1      | -   ReqUnset       Host: varnish
varnish_1      | -   ReqHeader      host: varnish
varnish_1      | -   VCL_return     pass
varnish_1      | Log abandoned (vsl)
varnish_1      | Log reacquired
varnish_1      | -   VCL_call       HASH
varnish_1      | -   VCL_return     lookup
varnish_1      | -   VCL_call       PASS
varnish_1      | -   VCL_return     fetch
varnish_1      | -   Link           bereq 9 pass
varnish_1      | -   Timestamp      Fetch: 1623449680.878425 0.011680 0.011680
varnish_1      | -   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
varnish_1      | -   RespStatus     201
varnish_1      | -   RespReason     CREATED
varnish_1      | -   RespHeader     Server: nginx/1.18.0
varnish_1      | -   RespHeader     Date: Fri, 11 Jun 2021 22:14:40 GMT
varnish_1      | -   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
varnish_1      | -   RespHeader     Content-Length: 31
varnish_1      | -   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 8
varnish_1      | -   RespHeader     Age: 0
varnish_1      | -   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.5)
varnish_1      | -   VCL_call       DELIVER
varnish_1      | -   VSL            flush
varnish_1      | -   End            synth
```

What could be happening? A race condition? Did I omit anything in the deliver sub? By the way, I noticed these issues without the ban commands too.

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE: following the commenter's advice, I inspected the panic dump:

```
Panic at: Mon, 14 Jun 2021 17:25:36 GMT
Wrong turn at cache/cache_main.c:287:
Signal 11 (Segmentation fault) received at 0 si_code 128
version = varnish-6.5.1 revision 1dae23376bb5ea7a6b8e9e4b9ed95cdc9469fb64, vrt api = 12.0
ident = Linux,5.12.6-arch1-1,x86_64,-junix,-sdefault,-sfile,-sdefault,-hcritbit,epoll
now = 148500.767810 (mono), 1623691535.535737 (real)
Backtrace:
  ip=0x55c79cbc5b19, sp=0x7f941dbf8460 <PAN_already+0x1304>
  ip=0x55c79cc1c8de, sp=0x7f941dbf85a0 <VAS_Fail+0x22>
  ip=0x55c79cbc1cb2, sp=0x7f941dbf85e0 <THR_GetRequest+0x14a>
  ip=0x7f941dd75c4b, sp=0x7f941dbf8ac0 <sigwaitinfo+0x8>
pthread.self = 0x7f9417c63b38
pthread.name = (cache-worker)
pthread.attr = {
  guard = 8192,
  stack_bottom = 0x7f9417c55000,
  stack_top = 0x7f9417c63b08,
  stack_size = 60168,
}
thr.req = 0x7f93f736eb20 {
  vxid = 32770, transport = HTTP/1 {
    state = HTTP1::Proc
  }
  step = R_STP_DELIVER,
  req_body = none,
  restarts = 0, esi_level = 0,
  sp = 0x7f93f737f030 {
    fd = 28, vxid = 32769,
    t_open = 1623691535.525822,
    t_idle = 1623691535.525822,
    ws = 0x7f93f737f070 {
      id = \"ses\",
      {s, f, r, e} = {0x7f93f737f0c8, +96, 0, +576},
    },
    transport = HTTP/1 {
      state = HTTP1::Proc
    }
    client = 172.18.0.5 57692 :80,
  },
  worker = 0x7f9417c63970 {
    ws = 0x7f9417c63a18 {
      id = \"wrk\",
      {s, f, r, e} = {0x7f9417c62f50, +0, 0, +2040},
    },
    VCL::method = inside DELIVER,
    VCL::return = 0x0,
    VCL::methods = {RECV, PASS, HASH, DELIVER},
  },
  ws = 0x7f93f736ec70 {
    id = \"req\",
    {s, f, r, e} = {0x7f93f7370bd0, +168, 0, +57128},
  },
  http_conn = 0x7f93f7370b48 {
    fd = 28 (@0x7f93f737f054),
    doclose = NULL,
    ws = 0x7f93f736ec70 {
      [Already dumped, see above]
    },
    {rxbuf_b, rxbuf_e} = {0x7f93f7370bd0, 0x7f93f7370c26},
    {pipeline_b, pipeline_e} = {0, 0},
    content_length = -1,
    body_status = none,
    first_byte_timeout = 0.000000,
    between_bytes_timeout = 0.000000,
  },
  http[req] = 0x7f93f736ed10 {
    ws = 0x7f93f736ec70 {
      [Already dumped, see above]
    },
    hdrs {
      \"POST\",
      \"/svc/reload_acl\",
      \"HTTP/1.1\",
      \"User-Agent: curl/7.64.0\",
      \"Accept: */*\",
      \"X-Forwarded-For: 172.18.0.5\",
      \"host: varnish\",
    },
  },
  http[resp] = 0x7f93f736f600 {
    ws = 0x7f93f736ec70 {
      [Already dumped, see above]
    },
    hdrs {
      \"HTTP/1.1\",
      \"201\",
      \"CREATED\",
      \"Server: nginx/1.18.0\",
      \"Date: Mon, 14 Jun 2021 17:25:35 GMT\",
      \"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\",
      \"Content-Length: 31\",
      \"X-Varnish: 32770\",
      \"Age: 0\",
      \"Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.5)\",
    },
  },
  vdc = 0x7f93f7370b28 {
    nxt = 0,
    retval = 0,
  },
  vcl = {
    name = \"svc\",
    busy = 1,
    discard = 0,
    state = auto,
    temp = warm,
    conf = {
      syntax = \"41\",
      srcname = {
        \"/etc/varnish/conf.d/svc.vcl\",
        \"Builtin\",
        \"/etc/varnish/conf.d/backend_default.vcl\",
        \"/etc/varnish/conf.d/acl.vcl\",
      instances = {
        \"idmap\" = 0x7f93f75fe070,
      },
    },
  },
  objcore[REQ] = 0x7f93f75d51f0 {
    refcnt = 1,
    flags = {hfm, private},
    exp_flags = {},
    exp = {1623691535.535603, -1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000},
    objhead = 0x7f941dc16890,
    stevedore = 0x55c79cc9dee0 (malloc Transient) {
      Simple = 0x7f93f75d58d0,
      Obj = 0x7f93f771ad98 {priv=0x7f93f771ad90, ptr=0x7f93f75d58d0, len=264, space=264},
      LEN = 0x000000000000001f,
      VXID = 0x00008003,
      FLAGS = 0x00,
      GZIPBITS = 0x0...0,
      LASTMODIFIED = 0x41d831e443c00000,
      VARY = {len=0, ptr=0},
      HEADERS = {len=144, ptr=0x7f93f75d5948},
      Body = 0x7f93f7593818 {priv=0x7f93f7593810, ptr=0x7f93f75d5c90, len=31, space=31},
    },
  },
  flags = {
  },
  privs = 0x7f93f736ed00 {
  },
  top = 0x7f93f7370bb0 {
    req = 0x7f93f736eb20 {
      [Already dumped, see above]
    },
    privs = 0x7f93f7370bc8 {
    },
    vcl0 = {
      name = \"main\",
      busy = 1,
      discard = 0,
      state = auto,
      temp = warm,
      conf = {
        syntax = \"41\",
        srcname = {
          \"/etc/varnish/conf.d/main.vcl\",
          \"Builtin\",
          \"/etc/varnish/conf.d/backend_default.vcl\",
          \"/etc/varnish/conf.d/synth.vcl\",
        instances = {
          \"idmap\" = 0x7f93f75fe070,
        },
      },
    },
  },
},
thr.busyobj = 0 {
},
vmods = {
  blob = {0x7f941860edb0, Varnish 6.5.1 1dae23376bb5ea7a6b8e9e4b9ed95cdc9469fb64, 0.0},
  blobdigest = {0x7f941860ee20, Varnish 6.5.1 1dae23376bb5ea7a6b8e9e4b9ed95cdc9469fb64, 0.0},
  curl = {0x7f941860ef00, Varnish 6.5.1 1dae23376bb5ea7a6b8e9e4b9ed95cdc9469fb64, 12.0},
  frozen = {0x7f93f7625020, Varnish 6.5.1 1dae23376bb5ea7a6b8e9e4b9ed95cdc9469fb64, 0.0},
  gcis = {0x7f93f7625090, Varnish 6.5.1 1dae23376bb5ea7a6b8e9e4b9ed95cdc9469fb64, 0.0},
  std = {0x7f93f7625100, Varnish 6.5.1 1dae23376bb5ea7a6b8e9e4b9ed95cdc9469fb64, 0.0},
},
```

I noticed that the panic doesn't happen if I remove the call to a function in a custom VMOD I built. This is the function in question:

```
VCL_INT
vmod_idmap_load (VRT_CTX, IDMap *idmap, VCL_STRING fpath)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *line = NULL;
    FILE *fh = NULL;

    idmap_clear (idmap);

    LOG ("Opening file %s", fpath);
    fh = fopen (fpath, "r");
    if (!fh) {
        VRT_fail (ctx, "Error opening %s", fpath);
        i = -1;
        goto finally;
    }

    size_t size = 0;
    int ret;

    while (getline (&line, &size, fh) >= 0) {
        char *id = strndup (line, UUID_STR_LEN - 1);
        //LOG ("UUID: %s", id);
        khint_t cur = kh_put (uuid_ht, idmap->ht, id, &ret);
        if (cur != kh_end (idmap->ht)) i++;
        else LOG ("Duplicate ID: %s", id);

        line = NULL;
        size = 0;
    };
    LOG ("%d identifiers loaded.", i);

finally:
    free (line);
    if (fh) fclose (fh);

    idmap->ct = i;

    return i;
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot tell from the dump where exactly it's segfaulting. Can I compile Varnish with debug symbols to find out more?

Comment: It seems like the `varnishd` child process dies and gets respawned. Please run `varnishadm panic.show` to see if any of the child processes have panicked along the way.

Comment: Yes, it does segfault. Updated description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to bet that the vmod code corrupted the stack, messing up the panic out, because that stack trace makes little sense.

Your best bet here, if you aren't sure what is wrong, is to sprinkle some `VSLb(ctx, VCL_Error, "at line %d", __LINE__)` to see how far you go using `varnishlog`.

One note though, you aren't testing a lot of your inputs and returns, I would advise asserting/checking a lot more. For example: https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules/blob/master/src/vmod_str.c#L15
Another example is that `strndup()` shouldn't fail, so you should have a `AN(id)` right after it.

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, the code is not yet production-ready. Even if the input is produced exclusively by our own software, it should have more checks. As for debugging, I will try the debug statements you suggest and get back to this thread.

Comment: I tried using `SLT_Error` (`VCL_Error` is not available in 6.5.1) but since the VMOD method is called in `vcl_init`, it crashes Varnish on startup: `Assert error in vsl_sanity(), cache/cache_shmlog.c line 111: Condition((vsl) != 0) not true.`. I noticed that `ctx->vsl` is NULL if called from `vcl_init`.

Comment: your current crash is almost definitely happening in `vcl_deliver` (see `VCL::methods` in the panic), so it shouldn't be a concern to debug this one crash.
But, if you want to log in `vcl_init`, you can use `VSL(SLT_Debug, 0, "at line %d", __LINE__)` which will log to id 0

Comment: Nice trick! I am actually going to use that for more generic logging. I am currently rewriting the VMOD with a more robust library because I isolated the crash to one specific call to an external library.

Comment: Yes. I had the same issue with the new library implementation and eventually found it was a bad allocation error. Not having much to debug this sort of issues in VMODs, it will help keeping an eye on these symptoms. Thanks.